# A pom.xml inside jar in META-INF\maven\ is not getting afect

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

i have added a dependency in my pom.xml like:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.excample</groupId>
      <artifactId>someJar</artifactId>
      <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

inside that jar, in META-INF\maven\com.excample\someJar\ dir, there is another pom.xml.

when i run `mvn clean install` all its dependencies not getting downloaded or added to classpath.

Is there any reason for that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you sure dependencies aren't downloaded? Do you use any IDE to come to this conclusion or do you know exactly where to look in the filesystem? BTW, one of the main purposes of using maven is to let maven worry for that kind of stuff and don't care anylonger.

Comment: you can cross check what all dependencies are added and skipped. using mvn dependency:tree

Comment: i did run dependency:tree. and the jars are not there under someJar dependancy.

Comment: Even I'm looking for an answer for this question.